# <Activity name> cannot be resolved or not a field

Tags: android

I'm trying to perform a simple navigation action using Intent.

I'm using the complete ADT bundle which includes eclipse, SDK and ADT plugins, so no need to configure ADT separately in eclipse.

1.) I started by creating two layouts named **activity_main.xml** and **test2.xml**.

2.) Corresponding java files are **mainActivity.java** and **test2.java**.

3.) Now **activity_main.xml** contains a button with **id = "click"** . Clicking this button should navigate to next activity i.e **test2.xml**.

4.) The code in mainActivity.java is as below

```
package com.example.test;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{

    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) 
        {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.click);

        //Listening to button event
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //Starting a new Intent
            Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), test2.class);

            startActivity(nextScreen);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

5.) But when i did so the **findViewById(R.id.click)** showed error saying "click cannot be resolved or is not a field"

6.) Eclipse suggested me to create a field click in id which i did. It modified the R.java file but it did not help. Though the errors were gone but the emulator threw error saying *"the application has stopped"*

7.) My manifest.xml file is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".test2"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.test.test2" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

8.) Now my **test2.java** code is

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.test.R;
public class test2 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test2);

     TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        txtName.setText("This is test2 activity");

}
}
```

Even here at **setContentView(R.layout.test2)** it shows the similar error as "test2 cannot be resolved or not a field" where as **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)** did not show this error

9.) My fragment_main.xml code is as below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/click"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:text="@string/button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

10.) My test2.xml code is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="second page" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

The error displayed on running the application is as below

a.) *[2014-04-15 18:39:03 - test] W/ResourceType( 8160): ResXMLTree_node header size 0 is too small.*

b.) *[2014-04-15 18:39:03 - test] C:\Users\KC\Desktop\Android-budle\test\res\menu\main.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').*

I'm not able to understand what am I missing. Please provide me a solution for this issue, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `R.id.click` in your `activity_main.xml` file?

Comment: where is your button click listener ? Have you tried to clean your project?

Comment: I commented that part but no good. The error is still the same, and moreover eclipse by default has also created fragment_main.xml so to make use of main_activity.xml that part of the code needs to be used

Comment: I have button listener but here it cannot find the button by id and throws error the very moment i type findViewByID(R.id.click)   and setContentView(R.layout.test2)

Comment: Post activity_main.xml. If the button isn't in there, that will throw this error.

Comment: You're setting your content of the MainActivity to fragment_main, which is also the layout of your Fragment. And there is no R.id.container in either. I suggest you go and have a look at some examples. Start with a simple Activity and work your way up to Fragments :)

Comment: The layout was changed from main_Activity to fragment_main after I recieved the instruction saying so from this forum. And this code was modified from a sample hello world program which eclipse generates automatically and all dependables are automatically created and loaded. The R.java file is also present.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity_main.xml>Button you need to put the android:onClick="methodName". The in your main_activity you schould implement methodName. There you can handle the activities once the Button is clicked.

Another way is to implement the onClickListener to sepertate the XML and the Java files.

Can you add your layout XML files?

Comment: This is bad practice. Don't do this. You should keep the java and the xml as separate as possible by adding an onClick listener in the Activity, not referring directly to a method from the button's xml markup.

Comment: That's right, you can also implement the onClicklistener in your Activity and handle it all in Java without XML

Answer (score 0):

Write the `onClickListener` for your button in your `MainActivity` `onCreate()` method and inside it redirect to `test2` activity as below:

```
btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.click);

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,test2.class);
                           startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

**EDITED:**

You need to set your view as `fragment_main.xml` besides `activity_main` as your `Button` is inside `fragment_main` layout.

Just change the

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to

```
 setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
```

Comment: It's not even finding `click` in R.id so this won't help.

Comment: I tried doing this even. But it showed error at the first step i.e        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click)

Comment: Thanks for updating on that. I did it but the error with R.layout.test2 and R.id.click still remains

Comment: Please post your error,your test2 layout code and the code of your `btn` click in your question. @user2470766

Comment: I have modified point 4, 9 and 10 and have also added the error that was thrown after running the application...

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong syntax wise with your `xml files (test2 or activity_main)` due to which the auto generated R file will no longer generate the id for the button view.

The main problem seems to be with `activity_main` as the button contained in it is no longer converted to its corresponding value in R file.

Check those files and if not able to figure out than put the code in order to get help.

Last but not the least check if you have the import statement like `import android.R`.
You don't need this to be there as it causes such errors if present.

**UPDATE:**

You are using -

**1)** setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

**2)** btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.click);

But your layout where you defined your button is `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);`

So btn is trying to find the view in activity_main which is not available.

**Solution** -

Set the content view to `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main)`.

Comment: Correct. There should be some syntax error in the file.

Comment: Actually its the fragment_main.xml i'm creating the button. Eclipse automatically created it when i created new application. I'll paste that part of xml code

Comment: I have added fragment_main.xml code as 9th point. please check it

Comment: Then why you have used `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` ? You should use `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main)`. Do that and check.

Comment: The problem is you are doing it within MainActivity (R.layout.activity_main) but your activity is MainFragment (R.layout.fragment_main).

Comment: Thanks @Ved Prakash for tipping me on that fault. As u suggested i changed it accordingly but it does not help. The R.id.click in onCreate of mainActivity.java and setContentView(R.layout.test2) n onCrete of test2.java still shows error

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Check your layout xml. I there is any error then correct it.After that `press alt+p` then select `clean` after that it will be build again.